# cordova_not_available when running on android device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I want to make a HTTP get request  using cordova-plugin-advanced-http but it returns me an error saying that cordova is not available. My problem is that it was working 2 days ago and since yesterday, it doesn't work anymore. 
Here is the error message:

```
[20:35:26]  console.warn: Native: tried calling HTTP.get, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js
            or run in a device/simulator
[20:35:26]  console.log: cordova_not_available
```

The code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private http: HTTP) {

  }

  getHttp(){
    this.http.get('http://ionic.io', {}, {})
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data.status);
      console.log(data.data); // data received by server
      console.log(data.headers);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

I tired to uninstall all plugins and platform and reinstall it, uninstall ionic and cordova, but with no success. All the solutions I found on google didn't worked.

[EDIT]
This occurs only when I run it with -c or -l flags

Comment: You should wrap your plugins calls within a platform.ready() callback.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to start your script with:

```
$$(document).on('deviceready', function() {
-- insert code here
})
```

Cordova is not available until the device is ready.  This means plugins will not be available until the device is totally loaded as well.

For raw javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
}
```

Comment: $$(document) is not recognized in my code, can you show me an example on how to implement it

Comment: Sorry I should have been more detailed, the $$ is my framework7, or you could use jquery.  For raw javascript. 

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use device APIs
}

Comment: Is this happening when you try it on a device, or when you are using the browser?

Comment: It happens when I try on a device